# Jquery : how to add <li> in an existing <ul> with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have code that looks like this:

```
<div id="tags">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and I'd like to append some items to the list using json data

```
 $.getJSON("data.json", function (data) {
            var html = '';
            var len = data.tags.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                html += '<li><a href="#">' + data.tags[i].tag + '</a></li>';
            }

            $("#tags ul").append(html);


        })
        .done(function () {
            console.log("second success");
           })
       .fail(function(err){console.log(err)});
```

but nothing happens , where is my mistake?

Comment: What error messages do you see in your browser's console?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the JSON returned by your call to data.json?

Comment: can you post a fiddle with your code?

Comment: We don't need off-site demos. You need to give enough information to reproduce the issue, along with error messages in the console.

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes,you're right I'm sorry.

Comment: @Terry I can't see any message in my browser console

Comment: @Nathan this is my json http://pastebin.com/KrrNyLG0

Comment: @Faby this is my code http://jsfiddle.net/kMbZG/1 .

Comment: @Klaus the problem in your fiddle is that there is'nt a direct call to json but there is a redirect instead.

Answer (score 5):

**Your Approach**

Your code will work fine as long as the JSON structure in your data.json is in the following format -

```
{
"tags": [
    {
        "tag": "Tag1"
    },
    {
        "tag": "Tag2"
    },
    {
        "tag": "Tag3"
    },
    {
        "tag": "Tag4"
    }
]
}
```

**Suggested Approach**

If your JSON is in this structure -

```
{
"tags": [
    "Tag1",
    "Tag2",
    "Tag3",
    "Tag4"
]
}
```

The javascript to make it work would be -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {
        var items = '';
        $.each( data.tags, function( key, val ) {
            items += '<li id="' + key + '"><a href="#">' + val + '</a></li>';
        });
        $("#tags ul").append(items);
    }).done(function () {
        console.log("Success");
    }).fail(function(err){
        console.log(err)
    });
});
```

This will generate the following HTML in your DOM -

```
<div id="tags">
    <ul>
        <li id="0"><a href="#">Tag1</a></li>
        <li id="1"><a href="#">Tag2</a></li>
        <li id="2"><a href="#">Tag3</a></li>
        <li id="3"><a href="#">Tag4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

working fiddle with test json

http://jsfiddle.net/BWM2E/1/

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D%27WRC%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback", function (data) {

    var html = '';
            var len = data.query.count;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                html += '<li><a href="#">' + data.query.created + '</a></li>';
            }

            $("#tags ul").append(html);


        })


        .done(function () {
            console.log("second success");
           })
       .fail(function(err){console.log(err)});
```

in for loop I print always created property because there is only one query element

the part of the json that I have treated is the following

```
{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2014-05-26T22:23:03Z"}}
```

in your case the problem is the url of json that make a redirect.

test it in [this](http://www.jsonblob.com/) (then click on "make a request") site and see this message error that explain you the problem

> We weren't able to successfully make a request to
>   http://myjtest.altervista.org/tagcloud/data.json.
>
> This is likely because of a Cross-site HTTP request and your server
>   not having the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin and
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods headers.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code, I don't think is the best choice but It worked for me http://jsfiddle.net/kMbZG/1/ . Thanx @faby !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your json file is invalid.
Maybe you use single quotes instead of double quotes or something else. Check your `data.json` file. 
According to your js code, your file `data.json` should be like this:

```
{
    "tags":[
        {"tag":"name1"},
        {"tag":"name2"},
        {"tag":"name3"}
    ]
}
```